# Inserting problem in php

Tags: php

Can u tell me what happen to my code?
it shows the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\dhiraj\queryverify.php on line 12

here is my code

```
<head>
<style>
#margin_left{margin-left:400px;
height:400px;}
#spanning{margin-left:70px;}
#spanning_gender{margin-left:66px;}
#spanning_marstatus{margin-left:27px;}
#spanning_city{margin-left:82px;}
#spanning_country{margin-left:62px;}
#spanning_religion{margin-left:63px;}
#spanning_crime{margin-left:74px;}
#spanning_crimetype{margin-left:39px;}
#table{border:thick;border-color:#09F;}
#insert{margin-left:140px;}
#foot{
background:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include('database.php');
include('commonheader.php');
?>
<form method="get" name="queries" action="queryverify.php">
<h3 align="center"><font face="Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif" color="#6C6">Queries</font></h3>
<div id="margin_left"><table id="table" border="1"cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<td>
Name: <span id="spanning"><input type="text" name="name" size="30"></span><br/>
Gender:<span id="spanning_gender"><select id="gender" size="1"><option value="r">male</option><option value="m">female</option></select></span><br/>
Marital Status:<span id="spanning_marstatus"><select size="1" id="marstatus"><option value="f">Married</option><option value="g">Unmarried</option><option value="h">Unknown</option></select></span><br/>
City: <span id="spanning_city"><input type="text" name="city" size="30"></span><br/>
Country:<span id="spanning_country"><input type="text" name="country" size="30"></span><br/>
Religion:<span id="spanning_religion"><input type="text" name="religion" size="30"></span><br/>
Crime:<span id="spanning_crime"><select id="crime" size="1"><option value="a">Murder</option></select></span><br/>
Crime Type:<span id="spanning_crimetype"><select id="crimetype" size="1"><option value="b">Half Murder</option></select></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="insert"><input type="submit" name="Insert" value="Insert"></div>
</div>
</form>
<?php include('footer.php');?>
<br />
<br/>
</body>
```

queryverify.php

```
<?php
   $name = $_GET['name'];
   $gender=$_GET['gender'];
   $marstatus=$_GET['marstatus'];
   $city=$_GET['city'];
   $country=$_GET['country'];
   $religion=$_GET['religion'];
   $crime=$_GET['crime'];
   $crimetype=$_GET['crimetype'];
   include('database.php');
    $query="insert into criminal(cid,name,gender,marital_status,religion,city,country,crime,crime_types) values(NULL,'".$name."','".$gender."','".marstatus."','".$religion."','".$city."','".$country."','".$crime."','".$crimetype."')";
 mysql_query($query)or die mysql_error();
  ?>
```

Comment: On a side note, this setup is extremely vulnerable to an attack called a SQL injection attack. (See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

You need to sanitize your data, or use prepared statements such as those found in PDO (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: was this fixed? if so mark the correct answer please!

Answer (score 2):

The $ is missing. Maybe in the future you should check the following if you have PHP errors (there the most common errors for every developer):

- did you type your query correctly
- do all the variables have their dollar sign
- did you add ; at the end of the line
- did you use the " and ' correctly

Also I see you get the different values but do not filter them, I suggest you use mysql_real_escape_string() before sending the query to the database

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
```

(just a few suggestions)